# AVL Tree - Print ascending using in-order

Tags: data-structures, sorting, avl-trees

Trying to understand how to write proof of correctness.
Searched over the internet on how to write proof of correctness but can't find a good solution for it.

The following sorting algorithm is proposed using the AVL tree: AVL input of all elements, and printing them in order.

**Algorithm  - Sort AVL (A[1..n])**

T -> Empty AVL Tree.

- for each 1 <= i <= n

  insert A[i] to T.

  print T elements by using in-order fashion.

Prove the correctness of the algorithm by showing the in-order scan of binary tree is always in ascending order.

Comment: There's nothing special about AVL trees here. The same result would hold for any  binary search tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVL trees, like all other binary search trees, have the following guarantee:

> Suppose that $v$ is a node with left child $l$ and right child $r$. If $x$ is a node in the subtree rooted at $l$ and $y$ is a node in the subtree rooted at $r$ then $key(x) \leq key(v) \leq key(y)$.

Using this, you can easily prove by induction that the inorder traversal of a binary search three produces a list of keys in nondecreasing order.